# Avada Wordpress wp_remote_get()

Tags: wordpress

Hello All I am at a loss of what to do on our word press site it is saying

> wp_remote_get() failed. Some theme features may not work. Please
>   contact your hosting provider and make sure that
>   https://build.envato.com/api/ is not blocked.

So I have contacted Avada and they said to make sure it is not blocked I have checked with our system admin twice and it is not blocked and he added to our exceptions list to make sure it can go through. I am still getting the error New to word press and Avada and not sure what I need to do next.

System Status from Wordpress and Avada

Avada Versions:

#### Avada Versions

Current Version: 5.4.2

Previous Version: 5.4.0  5.4.1  5.4.2

#### WordPress Environment

Home URL: http://landoll.com

Site URL: http://landoll.com

WP Content Path: /var/www/html/wp-content

WP Path: /var/www/html/

WP Version: 4.9.5

WP Multisite: –

PHP Memory Limit: 256 MB

WP Debug Mode: –

Language: en_US

#### Server Environment

Server Info: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

PHP Version: 7.0.28-0ubuntu0.16.04.1. WordPress recommendation: 7.2 or above. 
See WordPress Requirements for details.

PHP Post Max Size: 35 MB

PHP Time Limit: 0

PHP Max Input Vars: 3000 - Recommended Value: 4940.Max input vars limitation 
will truncate POST data such as menus. See: Increasing max input vars limit.

SUHOSIN Installed: –

ZipArchive: ✔

MySQL Version: 5.7.22

Max Upload Size: 35 MB

DOMDocument: ✔

WP Remote Get: wp_remote_get() failed. Some theme features may not work. Please contact your hosting provider and make sure that https://build.envato.com/api/ is not blocked.

WP Remote Post: ✔
GD Library: 2.1.1

#### Active Plugins (25)

Advanced iFrame: by Michael Dempfle

ARVE Advanced Responsive Video Embedder: by Nicolas Jonas

All-in-One WP Migration: by ServMask

Enable Media Replace: by ShortPixel

Enhanced Media Library PRO: by wpUXsolutions

File Manager Advanced Shortcode: by modalweb

File Manager Advanced: by modalweb

Formidable Forms Pro: by Strategy11

Formidable Forms: by Strategy11

Fusion Builder: by ThemeFusion

Fusion Core: by ThemeFusion

Gallery: by Total-Soft

Head and Footer Scripts Inserter: by Space X-Chimp

Post Types Order: by Nsp Code

Slider Revolution: by ThemePunch

Search Exclude: by Roman Pronskiy

SMTP Mailer: by naa986

Team Showcase: by Carlos Moreira

UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore: by UpdraftPlus.Com
DavidAnderson

Yoast SEO: by Team Yoast

WP Rocket: by WP Media

WP Smush: by WPMU DEV

WP Store Locator - CSV Manager: by Tijmen Smit

WP Store Locator: by Tijmen Smit

wpDataTables: by TMS-Plugins

Comment: what version of curl is on your server installed? it must be greater than 7.40...found it here: https://theme-fusion.com/forums/topic/status-warning-wp_remote_get-failed-cant-find-problem/

Comment: latest version is 7.59.0

Comment: Just talked to system admin going to back up the site and try upgrading.

Comment: So miscommunication on that he was thinking PHP version. So he went and double checked we are currently running 7.47 on curl

Comment: Just thinking out loud here could it be anything with ssl we are not using it just plain http

Comment: have you turned on error log? are there more informations?

Comment: No not yet how do I go about turning on the error log?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue with Avada Theme.

> Installing `php-curl` extension, fix the job.  Basically, I think
> behind the scene it uses curl to communicate with other endpoints.

But they should be given a warning like `Curl is not installed`, something like they are done for GD, ZipArchive etc.